# SImple Jquery ajax call not returning any data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am new to ajax and i have a task to get json object from the url but i cant get it

```
getNews : function() {
    $.ajax = ({
        url : corporate.newsService,

        header : {
                Accept : 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },

        success : function success(jsonData) {
            console.log("hello Json");
        }
    })

//  console.log(corporate.newsService);

},
```

**P.s Cant even get console.log message**

Comment: Add an `error` callback (like the success one) to see if it's failing...and why. It will give you the http status, and error message, etc.

Comment: If you can't get that console.log message, then you aren't invoking `getNews()`

Comment: @Matthew or the request is failing...

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte i am invoking that function but it doesnt get to $.ajax it gives me anything i console after that function

Comment: The console.log isn't firing, so the containing `getNews` method isn't running.

Comment: Your syntax for using $.ajax is wrong, get rid of the ` = `

Comment: @Kevin Good catch! didn't Notice that :/

Comment: @KevinB yeah got it thanks .. i didnt even realized ...I am new to it as i said before but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.ajax is a method, and not variable.

so

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Your URL',
    dataType: "JSON",
    success : function success(jsonData) {
        console.log("hello Json");
       }
    });
```

Or try to use

```
$.getJSON('Your URL', null, function(dataReturned){
                  console.log(dataReturn);
                 }
```